# If checkbox is checked then class add otherwise removed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

In my laravel project I want to add a functionality when checkbox is checked title name would be line-through otherwise not. But my jquery fucntion is not working. can anyone solve this problem?
THis is my blade file code

```
<tbody>
    @forelse($tasks as $task)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="icheck-primary d-inline ml-2">
                <form
                        style="display:none"
                        id="form-checked-{{$task->id}}"
                        action="{{ route('completed.update',$task->id) }}"
                        method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('put')
                </form>
                <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="icheck-primary d-inline ml-2"
                id="linethrough"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                if(confirm('Want\'s to complete the Task!')){
                    $('#form-checked-{{$task->id}}').submit();
                }
                "
                {{ !empty($task->completed_at) ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="myjqueryclass" id="clls-{{$task->id}}">
            {{$task->title}}<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody
```

and this is my jquery fucntion

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($id){
        // let myid = $task->id,
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('#clls-' + $id).addClass('addlinethrough');
                // console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
            }
            else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
                $('#clls-' + $id).removeClass('addlinethrough');
                // console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the class

```
<style>
    .addlinethrough {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
</style>
```

If anyone has other suggestion plz let me know. And one problem is If I mentioned class name instead of id then state is not saved.

Answer (score 1):

you can use toggleClass https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ , and your code will be like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function($id){     
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    $('#clls-' + $id).toggleClass('addlinethrough', $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});

// With vanilla javascript

const checkboxElement = document.getElementById("linethrough")
const elementWithLineThrough = document.getElementById("someId")

checkboxElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const checkboxStatus = checkboxElement.checked;

  // when the checkbox is checked, the class is added, if not, is deleted
  elementWithLineThrough.classList.toggle("addlinethrough", checkboxStatus);
})
```

Comment: Not working if I clicked nothing is happening. Did I something miss? In blade file should I've changed something?

Comment: can you use vanilla js?

Comment: I'm just using the simple jquery. I think the id is not correctly fetching.

Comment: I'm better with pure javascript, I added an example with it that can help you.

Comment: you can upload the problem to codesanbox or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a data-id attribute to the input checkbox.

```
 <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="icheck-primary d-inline ml-2"
    id="linethrough"
    data-id="{{$task->id}}"
    {{ !empty($task->completed_at) ? 'checked' : '' }}/>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            let id = $(this).data('id');
            $('#clls-' + id).toggleClass('addlinethrough', $(this).is(":checked"));
            if (confirm('Want\'s to complete the Task!')) {
                $('#form-checked-' + id).submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tested it with jquery-3.5.0 and it works